# How do I add multiple strings over several lines in Python?

Tags: python

I'm lost in Python world:

```
message = struct.pack('B', 4) +
    minissdpdStringEncode(st) +
    minissdpdStringEncode(usn) +
    minissdpdStringEncode(server) +
    minissdpdStringEncode(location)
```

It doesn't run. Do I really need to put this all on one line or something?

That would be messy in my opinion.

Comment: Do i simply need brackets around the whole lot?

Comment: Yes - parentheses around the whole lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two choices:

```
message = struct.pack('B', 4) + \
    minissdpdStringEncode(st)
```

or

```
message = (struct.pack('B', 4) +
    minissdpdStringEncode(st))
```

I usually find the second form with parentheses easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can continue a line by ending it with a backslash `\`:

```
message = struct.pack('B', 4) + \
    minissdpdStringEncode(st) + \
    minissdpdStringEncode(usn) + \
    minissdpdStringEncode(server) + \
    minissdpdStringEncode(location)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a backslash (\) at the end of each line of the statement except the last.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it.